# Laravel server execution process

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have few questions about Laravel that I need answers to.

(1) I have sent request to the server to execute the business logic. This business logic has so many processes like send emails, SMS and so on. Now, I sent request to the server and my computer goes off. What will happen? Does Laravel Execute the whole script or will it stop script execution?

(2) Does Laravel execute all server requests while my browser is closed?

(3) This question is based on my questions 2. If question 2 answer is No, then how can I ensure that all the statements of my request are executed?

Comment: There is a concept of `Queues` in Laravel. that will stored all the request in database queue and then you can execute by command `php artisan queue:work` please follow the https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues that may help you to achieved you need

Comment: About 1) You should avoid such actions. Whether it works depends on the `max_execution_time` configured for your PHP instance. But in general, everything that takes more than 3 seconds in a web app is considered bad and perceived as broken by the user.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel server **requests** like any other server request from the front end (Your Computer + Browser) are handled entirely at the back end (The Server). Reason: Laravel is a PHP based framework and PHP is server side code. Hence, execution takes place entirely at the server.

On the other hand, in other to keep the front end up to date with what is happening at the back end, server **responses** are sent back to the front end. These responses when they reach the front end can automatically trigger another server request or require user action to send another request to the server.

Armed with this information the answers to your questions are obvious:

> (1) I have sent request to the server to execute the business logic. This business logic has so many processes like send emails, SMS and so on. Now, I sent request to the server and my computer goes off. What will happen? Does Laravel Execute the whole script or will it stop script execution?

Yes, the script that the request was sent to will execute completely. The business logic process will only be interrupted if it sends back a response to the front end and requires another action by the user to complete. Examples: User email verification after registration, sms confirmation code request. However, these failures do not stop the script from completing execution, they only make the intended process (e.g. User registration) incomplete.

> (2) Does Laravel execute all server requests while my browser is closed?

Yes! It definitely and completely does. Your browser doesn't need to be open for the server machine to function. To put this in a funny way - Your browser close button / computer power button can't switch on/off the server.

There you have it. Once your request is dispatched to the server, the server employs several means to complete your request independent of your browser. Your browser typically handles Markup(HTML), Style(CSS) and front end scripts(Javascripts).

If you are very much interested on whats going on with your request back at the server with Laravel read this [article](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/lifecycle) on the Laravel Request Life cycle.